# Insert data failed using codeigniter and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

i have a little bit error when doing a simple registration form. My problem is the data that have input is not inserted in database.

But before i using horizontal form the data can be inserted in my database. I'm using MySQL. this is my controller :

```
function create(){  
$data = array(
            'nik' => $this->input->post('nik'),
            'nama' => $this->input->post('nama'),
            'tgl_lahir' =>$this->input->post('tgl_lahir'),
            'no_hp' => $this->input->post('no_hp'),
            'alamat' => $this->input->post('alamat')
        );
        $this->db->insert('profile_mitra',$data);
        redirect('admin/daftar_mitra');
    }
```

and this my view called tambah_mitra.php.

### View (tambah_mitra.php)

```html
<?php $this->load->view('templates/head');?>
<?php $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');?>
<body>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content-header">
<section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <!-- general form elements -->
          <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Tambah Mitra</h3>

            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <!-- form start -->
            <form role="form">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <?php echo validation_errors();?>
              <?php echo form_open('admin/daftar_mitra');?>
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">NIK</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nik" placeholder="NIK">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nama</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama" placeholder="Nama">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Tanggal Lahir</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="tgl_lahir" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">No.HP</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no_hp" placeholder="Nomor Handphone">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Alamat</label>
                  <input type="alamat" class="form-control" id="alamat" placeholder="Alamat Lengkap">
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                  <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">

                  <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                </div> -->
                <!-- <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                  </label>
                </div> -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->

              <div class="box-footer">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Simpan">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
        </div>
        </body>
<?php $this->load->view('templates/footer');?>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO!  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try closing your form

```
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Also to see the errors use

```
<?php echo form_error('nik');
```

and continue filling the (' ') in with your variables 
to see what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

it is not inserting because you did not define name of input filed.i think this is the reason of not inserting data. please try.

```
<div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nama</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama" name="nama" placeholder="Nama">
                    </div>
```